# ¿En JS ingresar los datos al arreglo y si ingreso un dato que no esté en el rango( 0-120) me pida volver a ingresar el dato hasta que sea correcto?

Tags: javascript

```js
let Edades = [];
const min = 0;
const max = 120;

let CantEdad = parseInt(prompt('Ingrese la cantidad de edades: '));

for (let i = 0; i < CantEdad; i++) {
  const Caja = parseInt(prompt('Ingresa la edad: ' + (i + 1)));

  if (Caja <= max && Caja > min) Edades.push(Caja);
  else {
    alert('¡Edades incorrectas!');
  }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cual es el problema? usa un while en lugar de un for

Answer (score 1):

Una forma sería pedirle una y otra vez que vuelva a ingresar la edad usando un WHILE si es que ingresa una edad fuera del rango.

Al ingresar una edad en rango la guardas con el PUSH y luego el FOR repite el ciclo para ingresar una nueva edad.

Este código funcionaría revisando el ingreso de edades una a la vez ,supongo que CantEdad es la cantidades de edades que quieres guardar en tu array Edades.

```
   for (let i = 0; i < CantEdad; i++){
        
        const Caja = parseInt(prompt("Ingresa la edad: " + (i+1)))
      
        while (Caja > max || Caja < min){
              alert("¡Edad incorrecta!")
             Caja = parseInt(prompt("Ingresa edad entre 0 y 120: " + (i+1)))
        }

        Edades.push(Caja)
    }
```

Comment: Hola Claudio, la condición del **while** es incorrecta, podrías corregirla?.

Comment: Gracias coloque un Y (&&) debería haber sido un O (||)

Comment: Gracias. funciona la primera vez. pero si vuelvo a ingresar la edad incorrectamente falla

Comment: Si cambias const por let, funciona bien, querer modificar el valor de una constante arroja un error, que no aparece en el normal desarrollo del for, ya que en cada iteración, creas una variable nueva.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let Edades = [];
const min = 0;
const max = 120;

let CantEdad = parseInt(prompt('Ingrese la cantidad de edades: '));

for( let i = 0; i < CantEdad; ) {
  const Caja = parseInt( prompt( 'Ingresa la edad: ' + ( i + 1 ) ));

  if( Caja <= max && Caja > min ) {
      Edades.push( Caja );
      i++;
  }
  else {
    alert( '¡Edad incorrecta!' );
  }
}
```

Con una mínima modificación de tu código, obtienes lo que necesitas.
La modificación, quitar del `for` el "`i++`", y ponerlo dentro del `if`, de esa forma, solo subirá el contador, cuando ingrese un dato correcto.

Comment: gracias a ti pude terminarlo al fin

Comment: Me alegra haberte ayudado!!